# The element type 'Iterable<Container>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am getting this error while rendering list of images in flutter Row of List

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../helper/mapIndexed.dart';

const List imageList = [
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/du8msdgbj/image/upload/w_560,h_240,,a_ignore,q_auto,f_auto/v1609697109/e42avkuozkqhh8u3dh70.png',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/du8msdgbj/image/upload/w_560,h_240,,a_ignore,q_auto,f_auto/v1609697073/ncuy4b9rnhrwjdwkp6dy.png',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/du8msdgbj/image/upload/w_560,h_240,,a_ignore,q_auto,f_auto/v1609697374/wf6qw4izw2mi1okmex39.png'
];

class SilpleCarousel extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Row(
     children: [
    // here is the issue
       imageList.mapIndexed((e, i) => Container())
     ],
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: either `childern: [...imageList.mapIndexed((e, i) => Container())]` or `children: imageList.mapIndexed((e, i) => Container()).toList()`

Answer (score 1):

if we use spreed operator `...`on List we can over come this

```
 return Row(
    children: [
    // here we can spreed ...
      ...imageList.mapIndexed((e, i) => Container())
    ],
  );
```